# Setting up static IP for all my connected devices on my network

Tags: router, static-ip

I have been told that I need to go into my router...Can anyone tell me how to do this?

My router: Netgear WPN824.

Comment: The specific way to do it depends on the router you have.  What do you have?

Comment: Install DD-WRT on the router and your life will be unicorns and lollipops =) Seriously, it makes everything better.

Comment: Like @MikeChess said, it depends on your hardware.  Also, are you *really* trying to set up *static IPs* or are you looking for *DHCP Reservations*?  The former technically requires no router configuration at all.  The latter is done entirely by the router.

Comment: Guys...Guys...I am overwhelmed by the speed and the quality of your replies (far too technical!)...Please slow down, thanks! Maybe I am too lazy and I need to get inside the router via admin access and see what needs to be done...

Answer (score 3):

First you go to the router and look for any writing on it.

Somewhere hidden within the cryptic lettering will be the name of the manufacturer and the model number of the router.

Next you go to the manufacturer's website, and head for the *support* section.

You should be able to locate your model of router within there, and they should provide you with an option to download the manual.

Once you have downloaded the manual, ***read it***.  There will be instructions in there on how to get into the router and make the changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically, since I don't know what the router is, but in general, what you need to do is either one of the following...

1. Disable the DHCP server on the router and assign addresses statically to each device.
2. Using the router DHCP server, assign fixed dynamic addresses per MAC address, for each device on the network.

So... what router do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done one of two ways:

1. On the router, find a way to change DHCP settings.

   - You'll have to know the MAC of the computer
   - Addresses will have to be in the same block (e.g. 192.168.1.xxx)
2. Change it on the desktop (on windows this is in Network Adapter Settings)

   - Addresses will have to be in the same block (e.g. 192.168.1.xxx)
   - Don't use the same IP on two machines
   - On Ubuntu, you can change it per connection (Network Connections)

Theses settings are only for the local LAN.  You won't have access to the specific computers outside of your network.  To get access, you'll need to do some clever DNS stuff.  Checkout dyndns.org or freedns.afraid.org for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way into most consumer-level routers is through the default gateway's IP.  You can find this by using the `ipconfig` command line utility.  Once you find it out, open a browser and put an `http://` in front of it, e.g. `http://192.168.0.254`.

Check your manual for the default administrative password, if it asks you for one.

Setting up static IP address assignments after this point is router specific and not all consumer-level routers support this.